# PyTorch LSTM data dimension

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I'm using every past 7 days' data to predict today's value (price).

For each day, there are 6 features (Let's call them feature1 - feature5, and price).

Suppose I have 1000 rows of data. Therefore, what should be the shape of my data to be used in LSTM Pytorch?

Is it (1000, 7, 6)?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM), LSTM requires the input of shape `seq_len x batch_size x input_size`. If you declare LSTM with `batch_first = True`, then LSTM would expect an input of shape `batch_size x seq_len x input_size`.

Now, in your case, since you have 1000 data records, I assume that is your training data size. You can split 1000 records into small batches and feed them to the LSTM.

For the `seq_len` and `input_size`, you can have the size `7 x 6` where `7 = number of days` and `6 = number of features`.

However, my concern is on your problem definition. In your problem, you have 5 features and `price` is the target variable, whose value you want the model to predict. So, you can feed the 5 feature values to LSTM and use the output vectors to predict the price value.

A reasonable network would be:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        # input_size = 5 (number of features), output_size = 50
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(5, 50, 1, batch_first=True)
        # output_size = 1 (target price)
        self.dense = nn.Linear(50, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dense(self.lstm(x)[0])
        return x

model = Model()
batch_input = torch.randn(16, 7, 5) # => batch_size = 16
y = model(batch_input) # => torch.Size([16, 7, 1])
```

Now, you can optimize the model using [MSELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MSELoss) since the task is more like a regression problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the past 7 days' data to predict today's price, and the past prices are also in my input. So the number of features is 6. What confused me is, since I have 1000 days' data, what kind of training set I should create. My aim is to create pairs (**past 7 days' records**, today's y). What the shape of **past 7 days' records** should be? 7 x 6 or 1 x 42? I think, if I simply split 1000 records into small batches, then the data will be non-overlapping which is not what I want.